# run pig on hadoop could not find the result

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I ran a pig script on a hadoop cluster, it pass successfully but i cannot find the result files, here is what it said:

```
Output(s):
Successfully stored 2 records (122 bytes) in: "hdfs://ocean-01/user/root/all_users"
```

i login to ocean-01 and could find such a folder as /user/root, where is it hidding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look in HDFS. Use this command (on ocean-01):

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/root/all_users
```